# Do SELECT COUNT from 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables STUDENT and COURSE.

STUDENT has the following columns:

```
SID INTERGER
NAME VARCHAR
DEPARTMENT INTEGER
REGISTRATIONDATE DATE
```

COURSE has the following columns:

```
CID INTERGER
SID INTERGER
ENROLLEDATE
```

I want to get total STUDENT count for each registration date, by department and also count of students enrolled in each course for that registration date which can be determined by ENROLLEDATE between REGISTRATIONDATE and REGISTRATIONDATE + 28

If my input data is :

```
STUDENT:
1,John,CS,11/01/2014
2,Jim,CS,11/01/2014
3,Jane,LAW,10/01/2014
4,Rose,Engineering,11/01/2014

COURSE:
1,1,11/10/2014
1,2,11/11/2014
2,3,11/11/2014

OUTPUT:
StudentCount,Department,RegistrationDate,StudentInCourseCount
2,CS,11/01/2014,2
1,LAW,10/01/2014,1
1,Engineering,11/01/2014,
```

StudentCount = Count of Students Enrolled in a Department on each Registration Date

Department = Department name for that count

RegistrationDate = Each Unique Registration Period

StudentInCourseCount = Count of Students in each Course where ENROLLEDATE between REGISTRATIONDATE and REGISTRATIONDATE + 28

Note: StudentInCourseCount for last row in OUTPUT is empty since Rose is not enrolled in any course.

Have tried to explain it as clearly as I can.

Here is my attempt but the StudentInCourseCount is not coming out right,

```
SELECT COUNT(sd.SID) As STUDENTCOUNT,sd.DEPARTMENT,sd.REGISTRATIONDATE,
(
    SELECT COUNT(p.SID) 
    FROM COURSE p
    WHERE sd.SID=p.SID AND p.ENROLLDATE BETWEEN sd.REGISTRATIONDATE AND sd.REGISTRATIONDATE+28 
 )  AS StudentInCourseCount
FROM STUDENT sd
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT,REGISTRATIONDATE
ORDER BY REGISTRATIONDATE DESC;
```

Thanks.

Comment: `select`, `join`, `group by`, and `count()`...

Comment: What is your best attempt so far ?

Comment: Added what I have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `Conditional Aggregate` logic to find `StudentInCourseCount` . Update : Osa E is right it should be Distinct Count.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT s.SID) STUDENTCOUNT,
       sd.DEPARTMENT,
       sd.REGISTRATIONDATE,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ENROLLDATE BETWEEN REGISTRATIONDATE AND REGISTRATIONDATE + 28 THEN 1
             END) StudentInCourseCount
FROM   STUDENT S
       LEFT JOIN COURSE C
         ON S.SID = C.SID
GROUP  BY DEPARTMENT,
          REGISTRATIONDATE
```

Comment: Missing distinct count and left outer join

Answer (score 0):

Minor change to above. You want distinct count for students and left outer join to get student in course count when zero

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.SID) StudentCount
  ,s.DEPARTMENT
  ,s.REGISTRATIONDATE
  ,COUNT(CASE
               WHEN c.ENROLLDATE BETWEEN REGISTRATIONDATE AND REGISTRATIONDATE + 28 THEN 1
             END) StudentInCourseCount
FROM STUDENT s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  COURSE c ON s.SID = c.SID
GROUP BY s.REGISTRATIONDATE, s.DEPARTMENT
```